# CMake: Extracting tar gives an error without a message

Tags: c++, linux, build, cmake, tar

I'd like to download a tar file and extract it in `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}`. All my attempts have failed, and I keep getting a non-zero return value. The following is an MCVE:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

set(QRCODE_LIB_URL "https://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/qrencode-3.4.4.tar.bz2")
set(QRCODE_LIB_DOWNLOAD_TARGET "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/qrencode.tar.bz")
file(DOWNLOAD ${QRCODE_LIB_URL} ${QRCODE_LIB_DOWNLOAD_TARGET} SHOW_PROGRESS)
execute_process(
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar xvz ${QRCODE_LIB_DOWNLOAD_TARGET}"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE QRCODE_EXTRACT_OUTPUT
    ERROR_VARIABLE QRCODE_EXTRACT_OUTPUT
    RESULT_VARIABLE QRCODE_EXTRACT_RETURN_VALUE
    )

if (NOT QRCODE_EXTRACT_RETURN_VALUE EQUAL 0)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Error: ${QRCODE_EXTRACT_OUTPUT}")
endif()

project(cmakeTarTest)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp") # this can be removed
```

The most problematic part is that the error doesn't show any message, which I don't understand. I've been using this same recipe (with `execute_process`) for a while to run many scripts, including python scripts. Apparently there's something different here I can't catch.

Comment: @Tsyvarev If you're referring to why both variables have the same name, this is how cmake merges stderr and stdout.

Comment: Oops, didn't notice that you used the same variable for both options.

Comment: BTW, remove double quotes around value for `COMMAND` option - everything within double quotes is treated as a **single** command line token, but `cmake` and its options (`-E`, etc.) should be different tokens.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for the hint. I figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution. The command should be like this:

```
COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" "-E" "tar" "xvz" "${QRCODE_LIB_DOWNLOAD_TARGET}"
```

The hint from Tsyvarev's comment made me realize it.

EDIT: I still don't understand why the error variable was empty.

Comment: The `ERROR_VARIABLE` and `OUTPUT_VARIABLE` are empty because they contain the output from standard error and standard output from the command being run.  The original command was `cmake -E tar whatever.tar` which isn't a valid file name and cannot be run by the system so nothing is captured on standard error or standard output.  The variable `RESULT_VARIABLE` contains an error value, and on Windows the value is: `The system cannot find the file specified`.